# Can I rename a table without breaking the final-release?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I use a 3 tier release system; alpha, beta and final. I'm using EF6 database-first approach to update my database model every time I make a change. Each release uses the same database, so the beta site is using the same data as the final release.

If I want to rename a table (and the related entity model) in my existing database, how would I allow the existing final release to continue working as normal (pointing to the old table name) and the beta release to point to the new table name?

Comment: "Each release uses the same database, so the beta site is using the same data as the final release" - maybe you should stop doing that?

Comment: I appreciate the comment @Colin, but my question was not "should I be doing this?". Our beta users will be our sales/marketing guys and have been made well aware of the consequences of using a beta site with live data.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of the issue from the users' perspective. Your problem seems to be that you want to update your database model but, because of your release system, you want to do it without changing the database model.

Comment: Well - just allowing the live model to continue working with the new database changes. Creating a view should work fine, I just can't play with it right now 'cause there'll be downtime ;)

Comment: Yup... will do..... if it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a View in your Datatabase:

```
CREATE VIEW [OldTableName] AS SELECT * FROM [NewTableName];
```

Comment: Is all functionality retained here? Inserting and updating too? And not so importantly - would there be a performance impact at all?

Comment: simple views (like select * from xy) are updateable and I don't think that there is a noticeable performance impact.

Comment: Details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx ("Updatable Views")